# SqlAlchemy Get Model from Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I have a sqlalchemy query object

```
query = db.session(Category)
```

and Im trying to filter the query further as below

```
query = query.filter(Category.tree_id.asc())
```

but instead of Category, I want it to dynamically retrieve the model from the query to use in the filter.

```
query = query.filter(query.model.tree_id.asc())  #the goal im trying to achieve.
```

My main goal is to extend wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField where I am able to filter the sqlalchemy_mptt model further.

```
class TreeQuerySelectField(QuerySelectField):

    ...

     def _get_object_list(self):
        if self._object_list is None:
            query = self.query if self.query is not None else self.query_factory()
            if hasattr(self.query.model, 'tree_id'):
                query = query.order_by(self.query.model.tree_id, self.query.model.left) 
# self.query.model should be the current query model

            get_pk = self.get_pk
            self._object_list = list((str(get_pk(obj)), obj) for obj in query)
        return self._object_list

    def iter_choices(self):
        if self.allow_blank:
            yield ("__None", self.blank_text, self.data is None)

        for pk, obj in self._get_object_list():
            yield (pk, self.get_label(obj), obj == self.data)
```

Comment: could you explain what mean `I can't import the Category`? sounds weird.

Comment: sorry i had to rephrase my question

Comment: could you please explain what it is for and what problem you are trying to solve?